# adding the name of a xml document to the element IDs via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, document

I have a xml document called "document-a-f-52.xml" with the following content.

INPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ws>
    <w id="w_1">how</w>
    <w id="w_2">to</w>
    <w id="w_3">add</w>
    <w id="w_4">document</w>
    <w id="w_5">number</w>
    <w id="w_6">to</w>
    <w id="w_7">this</w>
    <w id="w_8">.</w>
</ws>
```

I would like to add the numeric part of the document name '52'(assuming the name of the document is document-a-f-52.xml) to the id of the "w" elements as following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ws>
    <w id="w_1_52">how</w>
    <w id="w_2_52">to</w>
    <w id="w_3_52">add</w>
    <w id="w_4_52">document</w>
    <w id="w_5_52">number</w>
    <w id="w_6_52">to</w>
    <w id="w_7_52">this</w>
    <w id="w_8_52">.</w>
</ws>
```

I was wondering how I can get the numeric part (last two digits) from the document name and add it to the 'w' elements id.

Comment: Do you use XSLT 2 or 3? There you have access to functions like `document-uri` and `base-uri` to access the URI (which includes the file name) of a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the XSLT processor you are using you can pass the `numeric` via a param to your XSLT stylesheet.

Your XSLT could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="numeric" select="52" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- This template adds the 'numeric' value to the attribute 'id' -->
    <xsl:template match="@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'_',$numeric)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `numeric` param can be passed to the template by your XSLT processor.
For example, with `xsltproc` you can use

```
xsltproc --stringparam numeric 100 a.xslt a.xml
```

to get a result like

```
<ws>
    <w id="w_1_100">how</w>
    <w id="w_2_100">to</w>
    <w id="w_3_100">add</w>
    <w id="w_4_100">document</w>
    <w id="w_5_100">number</w>
    <w id="w_6_100">to</w>
    <w id="w_7_100">this</w>
    <w id="w_8_100">.</w>
</ws>
```

Other XSLT processors may handle the parameter passing differently.

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 3 or 2 you can access the `document-uri()`, `tokenize` it to find the file name as the last token and replace any non-digits with the empty string, so with XSLT 3 all you need is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:param name="suffix" as="xs:string" select="'_' || replace(tokenize(document-uri(), '/')[last()], '[^0-9]', '')"/>

    <xsl:template match="w/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select=". || $suffix"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2 you would need to spell out the `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"` used above as the identity transformation template and use the `concat` function instead of the `||` concat operator.